# Split DNS on Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, dns

My project requires Windows 7 machine to resolve DNS requests for a given set of domain names with a specific DNS server connected through an IPsec tunnel. All other domains can be resolved with the DNS server configured on the main adapter. 
The Name Resolution Policy Table (NRPT) appears to be a perfect solution for this requirement but it does not support GenericDnsServer on Windows 7, therefore, it cannot be used.
What are the possible options to achieve that?

I am also trying to explore if there is a way to add a record to DNS cache on Windows 7 machine. But it seems when we do DnsQuery() for a domain with a given server, the DNS cache is not updated. Even nslookup or Resolve-DnsName do not update the DNS cache. It seems the DNS cache can be updated by adding an entry to hosts file, which is not a good solution as it will fail if the domain name to IP address binding changes.

If there is a way to update the DNS cache then I can solve my problem by sniffing DNS request packets and resolving the domain names in the requests with my server.

It would really be a great help if someone can suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

@Arun Kaushal  Did you try to flush it? You can flush the local DNS cache using the ipconfig /flushdns command in a Command Prompt. It will update local DNS cache.

Comment: Yes, I tried to flush the DNS cache but it does not help. When I resolve IP address for a domain using DnsQuery(), a record is not created in DNS cache on the machine. The DNS cache entry is created when I resolve IP address for a name using GetHostByNAme() but this function does not have an option to specify the DNS server to use for resolving the name.

Comment: @ArunKaushal Are you using WinSocket? gethostbyname() function has been deprecated. The recommended is getaddrinfo() function. It requires more info, but might be more helpful too. Please have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfo